# Make Python ask question over and over until certain input

Tags: python

Everybody.

I'm making a software to crawl webpage and bring some information.

In the beginning I ask 3 questions like:

```
    print('What tipe of information you want?')
    print('1. Basic Information (Title, Description, No Index and Canonical);\n2. See the whole visible text;\n3. See top 10 words')
    print()
    resposta = input('Insert only number: ')
```

All 3 are running with:

```
if resposta == '2':
    print(output)

if resposta == '3':
    print('Top 10 keywords are:')
    print(top)
```

What I want to do is:

After the user input a number, I want to ask a question in loop, like:

```
Do you want any more information? Y or N
```

If he types Yes the codes brings him to the first question:

```
    print('What tipe of information you want?')
    print('1. Basic Information (Title, Description, No Index and Canonical);\n2. See the whole visible text;\n3. See top 10 words')
    print()
    resposta = input('Insert only number: ')
```

If he types "N" I print: `thanks, see ya`. And the program closes.

Would be glad if anyone could help. Thanks! :)

Comment: add `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the entire code in a `while True:` block. Then, break when the user types `No`. Outside the loop print `thanks, see ya`:

```
while True:
    print('What tipe of information you want?')
    print('1. Basic Information (Title, Description, No Index and Canonical);\n2. 
      See the whole visible text;\n3. See top 10 words')
    print()
    resposta = input('Insert only number: ')
    if resposta == '2':
        print(output)

    if resposta == '3':
        print('Top 10 keywords are:')
        print(top)
    inp = input("Do you want any more information? Y or N")
    if inp == "N":
        break
print("thanks, see ya")
```

Comment: Thanks, man! It works like a charm. I just had to put some more "print()" on the code, or the questions would have no empty lines beetwen then. But it works. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```py
ask = True

while ask:
    char = input('Do you want information?')
    if char.lower() == 'y':
        #do stuff there
    else:
        ask = False
        break
```